layering in leaflet map not working upon removal
i am adding a layer to map , and upon zoomout removing the layer , the layer is removing but residues are coming , which are removed upon interaction with map , so i thought may be tilebuffering is issue but innvalidatesize is also not working
this is my code to do this :
$(function(){
    map.on('zoomend', function (){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (search_port_flag){
                global_port_marker.fire('click')
                search_port_flag=false
            }
            if (storm_labels)
            {
                    
                    for (let atcf_id in storm_labels)
                    {
                        if($(`.typhoons[atcf_id="${atcf_id}"]`).prop('checked'))
                        {                            
                            storm_labels[atcf_id]['labels'].forEach((label) =>{
                                if (map.getZoom() > 5)
                                {
                                    map.addLayer(label) 
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    map.removeLayer(label)
                                    map.invalidateSize();
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }

            }
        },500)
    });
})

